# In WinEdt 6, how do I highlight a block of just typed text with no effect on the compiled document?

Tags: syntax, comments

I hope WinEdt6 is recognised as one of the best LaTeX's friends.

I write my LaTeX stuff, and when a para is considered done, I want to `\done{the completed para text}` so that it differ from what I type next in say ink and background color. When the next para is done I do \done{another completed para text} and so on. I define \done as "doing nothing" command `\newcommand{\done}{}` as I do not want any changes to my compiled document - only to ease my writing by visually separating the "done" from "yet to be done". How do I do that with WinEdt 6, perhaps using switches? Any ideas?

Comment: This question seems to have very little to do with LaTeX, and is only about how to tell WinEdt you're "done" with a paragraph (and whether WinEdt is capable of doing something with that information). This seems more suited to the WinEdt mailing list.

Comment: But this *is* a reasonable question and I don't see a reason to downvote instead of merely voting to close!

Answer (score 0):

Use comments, any decent editor will highlight it in different color and not affect rendering.

Example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus arcu magna, malesuada ultrices tristique iaculis, fermentum dapibus quam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce at urna odio, eu sollicitudin nisi. Sed non purus eu libero semper iaculis.
%%
%% TODO insert dates about imsum [from this website](http://www.lipsum.com/)
%%

Aenean pretium libero ac est aliquam ac consectetur nibh pellentesque. Morbi sit amet metus id enim pharetra interdum. Integer vel malesuada ante. Donec pellentesque erat eget neque imperdiet id posuere dolor aliquet. Duis quis accumsan nulla. Nullam eget velit egestas neque hendrerit ullamcorper. Donec et purus dolor, a bibendum neque. Vivamus lacinia pulvinar quam, nec blandit eros molestie eget. Fusce porttitor tortor nec tortor interdum.
%%
%% Finished
%%

Comment: A single "%" starts a comment starting from it until the end of the line.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what was wanted — from the question it seems that he wants WinEdt to recognise "\done" and change the colour of everything that precedes it.

Comment: per keyword customized highlighting... even in AucTeX some elisp coding would be necessary. Off-topic then it is.